# Win7: Stop sharing a network share which has been removed

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I have a Win7-system which was sharing a folder on an internal drive. I have copied the data to a NAS and formatted the HDD with the original folder on it. I did not remove the share before formatting it, thus now I have share on my system that I cannot stop from being shared, as - obviously - the path cannot be found.

How do I remove this share?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I have share on my system that I cannot stop from being shared

**Solution 1**:

> - Open your computer in explorer so that you see "Network" listed below the libraries, drives and so forth .
> - Click to expand "Network"
> - You should now see the shared folders as subfolders of "Network"
> - Right click the 'ghost' shared folders and hover/select "Share with" --> submenu "Advanced sharing".
> - You will now see a new tabbed window with a button with a little shield on it that says "Advanced Sharing"
> - Click that button.
> - You will now see a checked box at the top that says "Share this folder"
> - UN-check it.

Source [Windows 7 RC: Deleted, previously shared folders, still shows under my workgroup folders as shared.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-rc-deleted-previously-shared-folders/d328ce0d-b151-4c32-95d7-06a73c09b6ae)

---

**Solution 2**:

> Shares are listed in `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares` registry key, you can delete the entries there, after a backup of the key ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125996/en-us))

Source [How to remove a Windows share when the folder does not exist anymore?](https://serverfault.com/a/543350) by [lrosa](https://serverfault.com/users/30639/lrosa)

This second solution has been confirmed to work by the original poster.

Comment: There is no "Share with" or "Advanced sharing" for ghosts.

Comment: @Paul <shrug> try the 2nd solution.

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me.  But note:  1. You may have to start regedit as an administrator. To do this, search for it in the Windows start menu, right-click regedit, click "Run as administrator," and supply credentials. 2. You may have to reboot both the machine in which the share location once existed and the machine in which it shows up like a ghost. 3. The  full regedit location is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares